# Zero-initializing an array data member in a constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I've got an array of class objects, and inside the class object I've got another array that I'd need to initialize to all zeros.  The code compiles and runs, but my output is showing C
rather than 0.

From the header file:

```
class Cache {
private:
    int byte[16];
public:
    Cache();
    int getBytes(int);
    ~Cache();
};
```

From the cpp file

```
Cache::Cache()  
{
    byte[16]={0};
}

int Cache::getBytes(int j){
    return byte[j];
}
```

from the other cpp file

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)  //visual check of initializes main memory
    {
        cout << cache[i].getBytes(j) << " ";
}
}
```

Is this being set up correctly?  As I mentioned, getBytes is returning 'C's rather than '0's as expected.

Comment: Fyi: C++11 allows you to value-intiialize on the constructor initializer list: `Cache::Cache() : byte() {}`, for example. This will value-initialize each element, which for scalar's means zero-initialization, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's the way to do it in C++03 too. I added an answer, but I'm sure I've done this before, so I am looking for the duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know there is at least a few out there (I authored some, and I'm sure you've penned a few too =P). For the life of me I can't find them, however. Didn't know that was a 03x thing. I never really stuck to the middle-specs, waiting instead until we finally got 11.

Comment: @WhozCraig I wouldn't consider 03 as a middle spec. I would say 98 never really happened :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza LOL. I don't think you're alone in wanting to pretend that was the case =P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just use *value initialization* in the constructor initialization list. That is the idiomatic way of doing this in C++.

```
Cache::Cache() : byte()
{ 
}
```

Note that C++11 allows this syntax too:

```
Cache::Cache() : byte{}
{ 
}
```

In case you're wondering *why* this works, from the C++ 11 standard (note this also applies to C++03):

> **C++11 § 8.5,p10**
>
> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., **()**, shall be **value-initialized**.

That term *value-initialized* takes us to:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p7**
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type<sub>9</sub> with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - **if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;**
> - **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

The third option in this trips the value-initialization of each element; the fourth applies once we get to each of those elements because they're (a) no class types, so (1) and (2) are gone, and (b) not arrays, so (3) is gone. That leaves only the last one, and your elements are zero-initialized.

Answer (score 5):

In `Cache` constructor, when you do :

```
byte[16]={0};
```

You are only setting the 16th byte of your array (which is out of bounds, so this operation has undefined behavior). Array objects are default-initialized in C++, because you store `int`, no initialization is performed.

You can use `std::fill` to initialize it  :

```
Cache::Cache()  
{
  std::fill(byte, byte+16, 0);
}
```

Or you can use a regular for-loop over your array.

Comment: That took care of it.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong on many levels. The syntax you use does not do what you think it does. What you are doing now is essentially initializing 17th element of the table to 0.

In your case `memset` is probably the fastest and simplest. However, it would not work for complex types, so I would consider writing a simple snippet for general case like:

```
template<typename T>
inline void zero_init(T array[], size_t elements){
 if( std::is_pod<T>() ) memset(array, 0, sizeof(T)*elements);
 else std::fill(begin(array), begin(array)+elements, 0);
}
```

This will check if the type is a POD-type, which in this context means it can be initialized via `memset` and will put `0` for the whole table. If the `T` does not support it, then for each element an equivalent of `element = 0` will be called. Also the check is possible to be evaluated at the compile time, so most probably the `if` will be compiled away and a simple "one-liner" version will be created for each type at the compilation time.

You can call it via:

```
Cache::Cache()  
{
  zero_init(byte, 16);
}
```

Comment: The fastest and simplest way is value initialization (see my answer.)

Comment: Yup, for zero initialization it will be done at compile time. It probably makes no sense to use this in other kinds of situations (as a template for something else). But I think I'll leave it around, though your answer renders it pretty useless. Well, too bad I don't have standard in the head to come up with such nice answers. *So jealous*. =)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

```
byte[16]={0};
```

Array has `0` based index, so maximum index in this case can be `15`, not `16`. You are corrupting the memory.

Second, you have to loop through all the elements and initialize them. The way you are initializing will be done for one element only.

```
Cache::Cache()  
{
  for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
   byte[i]=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

memset is the simplest solution.

```
Cache::Cache()  
{
  memset(byte, 0, sizeof(byte));
}
```

Comment: `std::fill` works like `memset` for char types , but works properly for other types, so it's perhaps a better option (as well as being less prone to getting the arguments in the wrong order!)

Answer (score 0):

C++11 supports this syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
   int bytes[16] = {};
   
public:
   void print()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
      {
         cout << bytes[i] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Test test;
   test.print();
}
```

Basically using [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and the [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) (default contructor)